# Rails: Migrate database data with paper_trail gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, paper-trail-gem

I am using paper_trail gem for auditing database changes in two projects with the same database structure.

I am making many changes to database1 in project1 and want to copy those changes to database2 in project2. 
I want to get new changes and apply it in my databases.
I don't want to dump whole database1 and import it to database2.

I am copying table "versions" used by paper_trail to database2.

So now I have database2 with current data and have new changes stored in table 'versions'.

How to apply those changes?

```
changes = PaperTrail::Version.all
changes.each do |version|
   # update row
   # ??? what to write here 
end
```

Comment: seems like paper_trail doesn't store the new version of row, but only old version. so it is not possible to get the last version of data using only versions table, because the last version is stored in the table itself.

Comment: Your best bet is probably to restore multiple tables, but if you can really copy only the `versions` table, you could store the current version as metadata. See [docs section 4.c. Storing Medata](https://github.com/airblade/paper_trail#4c-storing-metadata). Either way is going to be painful. I don't see an easy way to do this. Copying relational data is always tricky.